# My for loop won't run in r

Tags: r, for-loop

I can't get this for loop to run.

```
loopLength <- length(vector_X)
i <- 1

for (x in 1:loopLength) 
  vector_Y <- Frame_X$column_a == vector_X[i]
  Frame_Y <- Frame_X[Vector_Y,]
  Frame_A <- Frame_Y$column_b == vector_X[i]
  Frame_Z <- Frame_Y[Frame_A,]
  Vector_T <- Frame_Y$column_c == Frame_Z[1,2]
  Frame_Z2 <- Frame_Y[Vector_T,]
  returnSum1[i] <- sum(Frame_Z2$column_d)

  Frame_Z3 <- Frame_Y[!(Frame_Z1),]
  returnSum2[i] <- sum(Frame_X3$column_d)`
```

I can run the stand_alone code block by replacing the i with an integer (it is only running from 1 to 20) and crosscheck the db and the results are correct. However, I can't seem to iterate it.

I think I'm missing something glaring about integrating a loop but I've looked and can't seem to find it.

It doesn't work when I try to run it as `for (i in 1:20)` either.
Nor do the inclusion or exclusion around brackets around the code block work         either.

Comment: Read `help("for")`. You need to create a "compound expression"  with `{}`. Also, R is case-sensitive. And you need to use the actual iterator variable inside the body of the loop.

Comment: Did you want to use `x` as your indexing variable for the loop? You seem to be using `i` even though that's defined outside of the loop and never incremented.

Comment: I see, I messed up the i and x. Thanks for the help and pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

The variable you defined in your for loop is named `x`, not `i`. If that isn't it, then the error might come from the fact that if Frame_Z happens to have 0 rows, then Frame_Z[1,2] doesn't exist! I think that step in particular is not very clear. I could help more if you posted an example data.frame and said what you want to do. Also, it would make your code easier to read if you used less steps and didn't name indices Frames (as in Frame_A and Frame_Z1). Also, I think using `dplyr` would be easier. Something like:

```
library(dplyr)
loopLength <- length(vector_X)
for(i in 1:loopLength){
    xval <- vector_X[i]
    Frame_Z <- Frame_X %>%
        filter(column_a == xval, column_b == xval)
    ...
}
```

I can't post more because I don't quite get what you are trying to do though.

Comment: Also what @Roland said about the brackets.